# Rails runner and ActiveJobs (compatible ?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-activejob

Necessary to run the job once a month . I need to call it in cron with whenever gem.
In this case use jobs or rakes ?

I can't run my job in console.

> rails runner 'MyJob.perform_later'

I'm using Rails 4.2

**ERROR:**

.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant MyJob (NameError)
    from /Users/leonardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in`eval'
    from /Users/leonardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/leonardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in`require'
    from /Users/leonardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/leonardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in`runner'
    from /Users/leonardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/leonardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in`'

**CONTENT OF MY JOB:**

class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
    queue_as :default

```
def perform()


    Veiculo.particulares.publicado.each do |veiculo|
        limite_dias  = veiculo.plano.dias_ativado
        dias_ativado = DateTime.today - veiculo.ativado_em.to_date

        if limite_dias > dias_ativado
            veiculo.update_attribute(:ativo, nil)

            VeiculoMailer.avisa_desativacao(veiculo).deliver_later 
        end
    end

end
```

end

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: Updated my question with error...

Comment: What's the content of app/jobs/my_job.rb

Comment: I don't think it's not an ActiveJob issue but maybe on how you call rails. You should call `bundle exec rails runner` or `bin/rails runner`